# Get Range of Groups of Cells Excel C++/cli

Tags: .net, excel, c++-cli, excel-interop

I have a Excel spreadsheet that I want to extract data from using .Net framework. The Worksheet looks like this in a way:

```
      A     B    C    D    E    F    G
1  |hello| by | it |____|____| it | is |
2  | Hi  | he | To |____|____|you | are|
```

How would I get two separate ranges to pull the two"tables" into two different data tables?

I understand there is

```
Excel::Range^ RANGE = Worksheet->Cells;
```

But for one I do not understand how to utilize Range. And two, after reading it apparently returns the whole range of the worksheet and does not separate the two "tables".

Does anyone know how I could get the ranges "A1:C2" and F1:G2"?

Comment: I'm not sure whether I really understood what you want to do or not, but if you want to create and range from A1 to C2, I would suggest that you try the get_Range method. Something like Worksheet->get_Range(Worksheet->Cells[1, 1], Worksheet->Cells[2, 3]); http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.get_range(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp

Answer (score 0):

[`Worksheet->Cells`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194567.aspx) is supposed to be the entire spreadsheet. You're asking it for a `Range^` representing all cells in the entire worksheet, and that's what you get. (Quoting MSDN: "Returns a Range object that represents all the cells on the worksheet (not just the cells that are currently in use).")

A `Range` object simply represents a group of cells; it's not innately tied to sub-tables within a worksheet, like your "A1:C2" and "F1:G2" are.

To get the sub-tables, use the [CurrentRegion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678.aspx) property. I believe the way to do that is to get cell A1 and call CurrentRegion to get A1:C2, and on F1 to get F1:G2.

(Obviously, better design would be to have your two sub-tables in their own sheets within the workbook, if possible.)

Answer (score 0):

```
//the namespace you'll need to include, Project->Properties->Add New Reference
using namespace Microsoft::Office::Interop::Excel;

//This is your particular Excel instance
Excel::Application^ xl = gcnew Excel::Application();
//I like being able to see the sheet for simple programs
xl->Visible = true;

Excel::Workbook^ wb = xl->Workbooks->Open(Path2ExcelFile, Type::Missing, Type::Missing, Type::Missing, Type::Missing, Type::Missing, Type::Missing, Type::Missing, Type::Missing, Type::Missing, Type::Missing, Type::Missing, Type::Missing, Type::Missing, Type::Missing);
Excel::Worksheet^ ws1 = static_cast<Excel::Worksheet^>(wb->Sheets[SheetName1]);
Excel::Worksheet^ ws2 = static_cast<Excel::Worksheet^>(wb->Sheets[SheetName2]);
```

Now we can get the ranges

```
Range^ rng1 = ws->Range["A1:C2","A1:C2"];
Range^ rng1 = ws->Range["F1:G2","F1:G2"];
```

Here is how to get the values of individual cells

```
String^ val1 = ws->Range["A1","A1"]->Value2->ToString();
```

Then another way to get the value of individual cells

```
ws->Range[((Excel::Range^)ws->Cells[(System::Object^)rowInteger, (System::Object^)columnInteger]), ((Excel::Range^)ws->Cells[(System::Object^)rowInteger, (System::Object^)columnInteger])]->Value2->ToString();
```

Answer (score -1):

Microsoft::Office::Interop::Excel::Application^ xl = gcnew Microsoft::Office::Interop::Excel::ApplicationClass();

Microsoft::Office::Interop::Excel::Workbook^ wb = xl->Workbooks->Open(path, Type::Missing, Type::Missing, Type::Missing, Type::Missing, Type::Missing, Type::Missing, Type::Missing, Type::Missing, Type::Missing, Type::Missing, Type::Missing, Type::Missing, Type::Missing, Type::Missing);
Microsoft::Office::Interop::Excel::Worksheet^ ws = static_castMicrosoft::Office::Interop::Excel::Worksheet^(wb->Sheets["Tabelle1"]);

```
            Microsoft::Office::Interop::Excel::Range^ rng1 = ws->UsedRange;
            // ----------------------------------------------------------------------


            for (int Rnum = 2; Rnum <= rng1->Rows->Count; Rnum++)
            {
                DataRow^ dr = dt->NewRow();
                for (int Cnum = 1; Cnum <= rng1->Columns->Count; Cnum++)
                {
                    if (((Microsoft::Office::Interop::Excel::Range^)rng1->Cells[Rnum, Cnum])->Value2 != nullptr)
                    {
                        dr[Cnum - 1] = ((Microsoft::Office::Interop::Excel::Range^)rng1->Cells[Rnum, Cnum])->Value2->ToString();
                    }
                }
                dt->Rows->Add(dr);
                dt->AcceptChanges();
            }


            
            for each (DataRow ^ dr in dt->Rows)
            {
                _dataGridView_main->Rows->Add(dr->ItemArray);
            }

            // Close Excel file after reading
            xl->Quit();
```